# single sign on possible for already logged in user on intranet?

Tags: asp.net, security, single-sign-on

I have an asp.net intranet application where a user is logged into. I would like to authenticate this same user on another asp.net application which is public and in a diffrenent domain.
Is it possible to somehow use his token securely that was created in for the intranet application ? So the user does not have to login again? what to use here, asp.net forms authentication?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

the thing what you want is called [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service).